# Assigning an image to a numpy array makes colors of the image change

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I load an image and add it to an empty numpy array:

```
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
im = imread('/path_to_image',mode = 'RGB')
array = np.zeros((1, 299, 299,3), dtype = np.int8)
array[0][:,:,:3] = im
print(array[0].shape)
print(im.shape)
plt.imshow(array[0])
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the output I get]

I expect the two images to look the same when displayed. The image seems to change when I assign it to an array with:

```
array = np.zeros((1, 299, 299,3), dtype = np.int8)
array[0][:,:,:3] = im
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `np.uint8` : `array = np.zeros((1, 299, 299,3), dtype = np.uint8)`?

Comment: You are right, using uint helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`im` and `array` should have the same `dtype`. You can explicitly define the appropriate `dtype` for the array of zeros (as suggested by @Divakar) or alternatively you can use NumPy's [`zeros_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html)  and [`newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io

im = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/crpfS.png')

array = np.zeros_like(im[np.newaxis, :])
array[0] = im

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(im)
ax0.set_title('im')
ax1.imshow(array[0])
ax1.set_title('array[0]')
plt.show()
```

[image: im and array]